# How to use prepared statements in multi user website?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Where (in code) to place elements of prepared statements in a website where many users interact with the database?

I'm converting my code from using `$mysqli->escape_string` to using prepared statements since people say it's better way for protection against sql injection.

Is it simply removing all `$mysqli->escape_string`s and also replacing other parts of my code like this:

```
$mysqli->query("update `users` set `email`='$newEmail' where `userid`={$_SESSION['userid']} limit 1");
```

replaced with this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update `users` set `email`=? where `userid`=? limit 1");
$stmt->bind_param('si',$newEmail,$_SESSION['userid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

?

People say prepared statements is more efficient as statement template is prepared only once and then it can be re-used with different parameters. But in the code replacement above **wouldn't the template preparation be done every time any user wants to update their email address?** Should i instead prepare all statements when server is started? And don't prepare them again? (Though i don't know how to do that.) Where should the `prepare`, `bind_param` and `close` be placed throughout my website's code?

Comment: ___wouldn't the template preparation be done every time___ Yes, but thats not a probelm

Comment: ___Should i instead prepare all statements when server is started___ No, not really possible as nowhere to store the prep'd statement

Comment: The re-use concept comes when for example you are updating 20 row in the DB with 20 inputs from a form all gathered in one hit. Then you prepare the statement **once outside** the loop and just pump parameters into the execute inside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it simply removing all $mysqli->escape_strings and also replacing variables with placeholders

Yes.

> People say prepared statements is more efficient as statement template is prepared only once and then it can be re-used with different parameters.

Forget about it. There is no way to re-use a prepared statement between requests.

It works within a statement variable only and and therefore only applicable only within a single PHP instance. Means you only can use it for repeated inserts/updates. And even there the gain is not something significant.

That's more of a marketing trick than a really useful feature.